# I want to group the data and transform it into different format in mogodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, data-transform

This is my goal schem that store the goal

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    userName: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
    },
    firstName: {
      type: String,
    },
    lastName: {
      type: String,
    },
    currency: {
      type: String,
    },
    promotionCompany: {
      type: String,
    },
    displayNameInPublicRankingPage: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    surpriceContribution: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    surpriceContributionAmount: {
      type: String,
    },
    profileImage: {
      type: String,
    },
    bannerImage: {
      type: String,
    },
    setAutoPost: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    agreeTermConditions: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    status: {
      type: String,
      default: true,
    },
    role: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["fighter", "companion"],
      default: "fighter",
    },
    followers: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
      },
    ],
    cart: [
      {
        shopType: {
          type: String,
          enum: ["goal", "surprise"],
          default: "goal",
        },
        goal: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Goal" },
        quantity: Number,
        goalType: String,
        amount: String,
        senderMessage: String,
        fighterId: String,
      },
    ],
    socialLinks: [
      {
        platform: {
          type: String,
          enum: [
            "Facebook",
            "Twitter",
            "Instagram",
            "LinkedIn",
            "Tiktok",
            "Other",
          ], // Adjust as needed
          required: true,
        },
        link: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        status: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

This is my goal schem that store the goal

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const goalSchema = new Schema({
      goalName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      goalPrice: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
      },
      goalType: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['single', 'subscription', 'crowd'],
        default: 'single', 
      },
      goalPurchaseType: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['single', 'multiple'],
        default: 'multiple', 
      },
      goalCategory: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      goalImage: {
        type: String, 
        required: true,
      },
      status: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['active', 'unactive'],
        default: 'active', 
      },
      creator: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
      }
 
  },{
    timestamps: true,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Goal', goalSchema);
```

When user request to view the cart i want the cart data to be group on the basis of fighterId and format the data in the following order

```
{
  "cart": [
    {
      "wisher": {
        "wisher_id": "63325fa1743c2a0004f30b29",
        "name": "Goddess Mariah",
        "userName": "ineeddmariah",
        "profileImage": "https://wishtender.s3.amazonaws.com/images/profileImages/6df12e17-793c-4159-9fb3-3fa7af2d712f.png",
        "Wishercurrency": "USD"
      },
      "cartItem": [
        {
          "id": "cart_id",
          "goalType": "tip",
          "quantity": 1,
          "goalImage": "goal_image",
          "goalPurchaseType": "single",
          "goalName": "example_goal_name",
          "goalPrice": "209"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      // Additional cart items can be added here if needed
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You can use an aggregation pipeline to achieve this. 
[MongoDB Aggrigation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/)

Comment: "Hi @FaizanAshiq, it is possible to achieve, but I'm not sure how to do it. Could you please suggest a solution?"

Comment: I would suggest you to create a separate schema for cart and add references to other docs instead of embedding. Then you can simply use find query to find docs with options (third arg in find) to get cart items with populated result.  you can pass populate, sort, projection inside options while using find.
i am confused about property names in your desired result. eg. wisher?